# Convert for loop to forEach Lambda

Tags: java, arrays, lambda, java-8

I am learning about Lambdas and am having a little difficulty in a conversion. I need to introduce a List into which the array supplied by the values method of the Field class is copied, using the asList method of the class Arrays. Then I need to convert the for loop with a forEach internal loop using a lambda expression as its parameter. The body of the lambda expression will be the code that is the current body of the for loop. I believe I have the List syntax correct ( List list = Arrays.asList(data); ), but I am having a hard time on figuring out what to do with the for loop, or even where to start with it. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

```
public AreaData(String... data)
{
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList(data);


    /* Assert to check that the data is of the expected number of items. */
    assert data.length == Field.values().length : "Incorrect number of fields";

    for( Field field : Field.values() )
    {
        int width;
        String formatString;
        if( field == NAME )
        {
            /* Get the name value and store it away. */
            String value = data[field.position()];
            strings.put(field, value);
            /* Get the needed width of the field to hold the name. */
            width = max(value.length(), field.getFieldHeading().length());
            formatString = "s";
        } else
        {
            /* If the value is of the wrong form, allow the NumberFormatException
               to be thrown. */
            Double value = Double.parseDouble(data[field.position()]);
            /* Assertion to check value given is positive.  */
            assert value.compareTo(0.0) >= 0 :
                    "invalid " + field.name() + " value=" + value.toString();
            /* Get the field value and store it away. */
            doubles.put(field, value);
            /* Get needed width of the field to hold the heading or value. */
            width = max((int) log10(value) + MINIMUM,
                    field.getFieldHeading().length() + HEADING_SEPARATION);
            formatString = ".2f";
        }
        /* Keep the widest value seen, and record the corresponding format. */
        if( width > WIDTHS.get(field) )
        {
            WIDTHS.put(field, width);
            FORMATS.put(field, "%" + width + formatString);
        }
    }
    /* Optimization: to avoid doing this every time a comparison is made. */
    this.nameCaseless = strings.get(NAME).toUpperCase().toLowerCase();
}
```

Comment: As far as I can tell there's no reason to use a lambda here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Stream.of(Field.values()).forEach()` should do the trick:

```
public AreaData (String... data) {
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList(data);
        /* Assert to check that the data is of the expected number of items. */
        assert data.length == Field.values().length : "Incorrect number of fields";
        int width;
        String formatString;
        Stream.of(Field.values()).forEach(
                field -> {
                    if (field == NAME) {
                        /* Get the name value and store it away. */
                        String value = data[field.position()];
                        strings.put(field, value);
                        /* Get the needed width of the field to hold the name. */
                        width = max(value.length(), field.getFieldHeading().length());
                        formatString = "s";
                    } else {
                        /* If the value is of the wrong form, allow the NumberFormatException
                           to be thrown. */
                        Double value = Double.parseDouble(data[field.position()]);
                        /* Assertion to check value given is positive.  */
                        assert value.compareTo(0.0) >= 0 :
                                "invalid " + field.name() + " value=" + value.toString();
                        /* Get the field value and store it away. */
                        doubles.put(field, value);
                        /* Get needed width of the field to hold the heading or value. */
                        width = max((int) log10(value) + MINIMUM,
                                field.getFieldHeading().length() + HEADING_SEPARATION);
                        formatString = ".2f";
                    }
                    /* Keep the widest value seen, and record the corresponding format. */
                    if (width > WIDTHS.get(field)) {
                        WIDTHS.put(field, width);
                        FORMATS.put(field, "%" + width + formatString);
                    }
                });

        /* Optimization: to avoid doing this every time a comparison is made. */
        this.nameCaseless = strings.get(NAME).toUpperCase().toLowerCase();
    }
```

That said, you should consider the following rule of thumb:

> A lambda expression should be ideally up to 3 lines of code and in no
>   case more than 5 lines!

Comment: Thanks for the answer alfasin! I think I follow what you did, and it makes sense to me. But, with creating the ( List<String> list = Arrays.asList(data); )  Shouldn't the Lambda for loop reference that? Or should this simply be ( Arrays.asList(data); )?

Comment: @TheDude76 I don't see any reference to the `list` defined in `List<String> list = Arrays.asList(data);` so I suspect that this line can be deleted.

Comment: Where did that rule of thumb come from? In my book, a lambda expression should ideally fit on one line of reasonable length.

Comment: @StuartMarks that's why I used "up to". One line is the ultimate, but 3 lines  are still pretty readable like `CheckPersonEligibleForSelectiveService` example here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html

Comment: @StuartMarks funny enough, I just favorite'ed one of your last tweets (probably more or less at the same time you commented to this answer :)))

Comment: @alfasin Aha, so that was you! It took me a while to crack your code. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you particularly want to convert this to using streams and lambdas then I feel you should also take the opportunity to refactor it in line with the intent of these tools. That means using filters, collectors etc. rather than just convert all your code to a single lambda.

For example something like:

```
Arrays.stream(Field.values())
    .peek(field -> field.storeValue(data))
    .filter(field -> field.getWidth(data) > widths.get(field))
    .forEach(field -> storeWidthAndFormat(data, widths, formats));
```

This assumes you encapsulate logic associated with NAME inside the `Field` enum (which is what I would recommend).